# Associate specific person or place with an image

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image

What I want to do is when I select data that holds the text New Jersey, an image that is associated with that text of New Jersey comes up. Is there any way to make this simple? I know I can do a database like

```
| New Jersey | img.com/picture |
```

inside of a table but to go through and put image links on 1000+ rows might be excess if there is an easier way.

```
echo $row["name"] ;
```

returns as New Jersey in text

I want it to return an image I have associated with New Jersey instead of the text New Jersey.

So my database is

```
New Jersey | info | info | info
Oregon     | info | info | info
New Jersey | info | info | info
Vermont    | info | info | info
```

Whenever I return with New Jersey I want it to change to an image of New Jersey.

Edit: Nevermind, I just went and used my superb excel skills to fill out a table with all the links. I'm glad people helped correct the grammar and code blocks though. It really helped me move on from my issue. Instead of learning anything I just did what I do best. Appreciate it!

Comment: This is very unclear. We need a lot more context, and show what code you've written so far.

Comment: I can't put the code I've written for this yet because I don't have any. My current only idea or option is to go through all the rows in my database and add the image for each one. I'm simply asking for a more simple way of doing this instead of entering 1000 of links I just have to enter 100.